# How to breakline on heading of article?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

For example, title is too long, so how do I have linebreak there?

Style file is: `iopart.cls`

`\title{asdasdfasdfasdfasdfadsffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfsdfsdwefwkewfw9fhowufuwnsndnsndnsdnvlnsldnnslnflwnefnlwenklfnwlenfklwnelkfnklewnklfwefffffff}`

[image]

Comment: huh, what a long word! does it really exist? if your long title is composed from many (normal long) words than breaking title into more line should not be a problem.

Comment: @Zarko unfortunately, it is long......I tried line breaking, but it only works on title not heading.

Comment: please provide small but complete document that we can see what is going on. do you really need so long word in heading? does not exist a much shorter synonym? after your comment your question is less clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IOP template (iopart) allows to set a running title, which is displayed in the header line of each page. You can set this via:

```
\title[short running title]{much longer full title}
```